# Логика поиска ходов в массиве

Tags: java, алгоритм

Я делаю игру крестики нолики и как мы все знаем там есть банальная логика победы/ничьи. Реализовав ее на простом уровне , понял, что она не идеальна и  ее нужно сделать более гибкой. То есть, если нет выигрышных ходов, до конца поле не заполнено, то смысла продолжать партию нет.

Вот мой код логики:

```
private final int[][] pole;
public boolean allCellsFilled;

public GameLogic(int[][] pole) {
    this.pole = pole;
}
public boolean allCellsFilled() {
    allCellsFilled = true; // Изначально считаем, что все ячейки заполнены

    // Проверка всех ячеек
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (pole[i][j] == 0) {
                allCellsFilled = false; // Если хоть одна ячейка не заполнена, изменяем значение на false
                return false; // Нет смысла продолжать проверку, если найдена хоть одна незаполненная ячейка
            }
        }
    }
    return true; // Если все ячейки заполнены, возвращаем true
}

public boolean checkWin(int player) {
    // Проверка строк
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (pole[i][0] == player && pole[i][1] == player && pole[i][2] == player) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Проверка столбцов
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (pole[0][j] == player && pole[1][j] == player && pole[2][j] == player) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Проверка диагоналей
    return (pole[0][0] == player && pole[1][1] == player && pole[2][2] == player) ||
            (pole[0][2] == player && pole[1][1] == player && pole[2][0] == player); // Ни одно из условий победы не выполнено
}
```

Comment: И какой вопрос?

Comment: Почитайте об алгоритме "минимакс". С его помощью можно очень легко реализовать бота для крестиков-ноликов.

Comment: @Эникейщик щас логика проверки на ничью тупо, что 9 ячеек заполнены, но в реально жизни никто не будет доигрывать, если и так понятно. что партия закончена нечьей. Как заставить проверять такую тему, типа есть ли выигрышные комбинации еще или нет

Comment: Как обычно: сначала решить задачу на бумажке, а потом уже переносить решение в код.